# How to use remote DB with Wakanda Studio v2.0.1?

Tags: wakanda, 4d-database

I use the new version of Wakanda Studio, v2.0.1.
How do I connect Wakanda to 4D database?

I right click and I can't find "Connect to Remote Datastore".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on **models** --> **new** --> **Model** and select **4D** in **Datastore type** dropdown

Comment: @Pratoux Don't hesitate to tag the right answer to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use an Enterprise version ? 4D connector is not shipped with Community version

Otherwise, the remote datastore interface is now available with a right click on `/backend/models/` directory, then `New > Model`.